# PHP Logout script not redirecting correctly

Tags: php, jquery, session

So I'm using jQuery mobile and PHP to log out of my website via this code

To access the logout code you click on the logout button. coded like this

```
  <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
           <ul>
                <li><a href="logout.php" data-transition="none" data-icon="delete">Sign Out</a></li>
           </ul>
       </di>
  </div>
```

this is the logout.php script

```
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header('location: login.php');
```

It works in logging me out and taking me to login page, but the url is

```
 mysite.com/logout.php
```

instead of

```
 mysite.com/login.php
```

It displays the login.php information but the url is wrong. How do I fix that?

Comment: Did you make sure not to echo anything out after changing the header?

Comment: _"[...It works in logging me out and taking me to login page...]"_ How can it take you to the login page if the url doesn't change?

Comment: A blank page usually means that error reporting is turned off, errors or warnings are generated but you don't see them. Also it's good idea to use `exit()` after `header('location: page.php')` incase you have more code coming after the header and the user agent doesn't follow location headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using links to a page outside a mobile framework such as jQuery mobile, you  MUST include `rel="external">` in the href.

For example:

```
<a href="logout.php" data-transition="none" data-icon="delete" rel="external">Sign Out</a>
```

**this is extremely important**, otherwise it will think you want it to remain in the same page you came in from.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
header('Location: login.php');
die();
```

Is there any error thrown?

BTW: you can also try this:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=login.php'>");
```

Comment: Here, `die()` is important, it stops the page from further loading and redirects to the header location. +1

Comment: as far as i know i have no errors i added both examples you gave me neither seem to work. i also edited the question to show a live example

Comment: It seems to work properly. In your live test I could login and logout, ending the script in the login page again without blank pages

Comment: So I'm using >> **jQuery mobile** << and PHP to log out of my website via this code

Comment: I just added my answer and that is what i did to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change

```
 <li><a href="logout.php" data-transition="none" data-icon="delete">Sign Out</a></li>
```

To

```
 <li><a href="logout.php" data-transition="none" data-icon="delete" rel="external">Sign Out</a></li>
```

someone pointed out that with jquery mobile it thought i wanted to stay in the page so i needed to add `rel="external"`

i also added `die("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=login.php'>");` to the script

Both of those fixed the problem

Comment: that's what I wrote in a commment `rel="external"` (15 mins ago), but you never bothered answering me. So I deleted it. You really should check comments, they stand at being just as important than posted answers.

Comment: well when i got to trying it and came back to thank you, you had deleted it!

Comment: I'm not going to wait around for 15 mins. I have better things to do. I've been working with jQuery mobile since it came out.